# Android Share - special characters in title became HTML entities

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

I used the *Share* feature to share [a question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/192367/45721) on *WhatsApp*. The question title is:

> Does the word "out" carry sexual-minority flavour?

Here's what I got:

[image]

Also tried sending the share intent to other apps. *Messaging* and *Gmail*:

[image]
[image]

Note that *Facebook* is a bad test candidate for this bug. The *Facebook* app seems to fetch the title directly from *Stack Exchange* website (ignoring the share intent text).

<sup>Stack Exchange app v1.0.48

Android JB (4.3)

Samsung Galaxy S3 LTE (GT-I9305)

Stock ROM (rooted)</sup>

Comment: Hmm... can't seem to share on WhatsApp with the iOS app so can't really repro, but when sharing via text message or email, the quotes are preserved.

Comment: @ShadowWizard It's an Android app issue, but good to know that the iOS app does not have it `:)`

Comment: I'm able to reproduce this on a Nexus 5 running stock 4.4.4

Comment: @ADTC and when you share via message or email, it's also borked?

Comment: @ShadowWizard I have already included screenshots showing that the answer to your question is, *yes*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is fixed in next update, thanks!